# IMF CODE FEES REQUIREMENT

Tags: scams, fees

Is this a scam that financial services institutions in order for them to release?
my established savings account with them to transfer funds in united states.

It says I have to put out and pay eight-thousand and three hundred plus dollars to
transfer funds from their established account savings to united states my account.

I read that IMF does not deal with private accounts on banks.

Comment: yes this is a scam. don't pay.

Comment: And there’s no savings account and no money.